# How to set a background image for a card in CardView?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a card and want to add content to it. How should I add images and also Text to the card? Here is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ml.vedantk.app.god.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="389dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the java file:

```
package ml.vedantk.app.god;

import android.support.annotation.ColorInt;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CardView card1 = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card1);
        card1.setCardBackgroundColor(100);

    }
}
```

The `card1.setCardBackgroundColor(100);` also did not change the background color. So can anybody help me add an image?

Comment: it should be `setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.someColorName)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Image can't be set as Background Image For a Card View.But You can Use Background Color using `setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))`

If you want to set a background Image Inside Cardview Use Another Layout such as `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or any other Inside The CardView. And Add Background for that Layout. This is one of the easy way to set BackgroundImage for CardView

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this?

```
card1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure your answer must be working, but I will be using Tomin B answer

Comment: The issue with this is it breaks the corner radius on the cardview.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without losing your cardcorner radius.
Here's my XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/zoneback"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".kidzone">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/quizcard"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/quizimage"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You will have to create a custom `Drawable` :

```
public class RoundCornerDrawable extends Drawable {
    private final float mCornerRadius;
    private final RectF mRect = new RectF();
    //private final RectF mRectBottomR = new RectF();
    //private final RectF mRectBottomL = new RectF();
    private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final int mMargin;

    public RoundCornerDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, float cornerRadius, int margin) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mMargin = margin;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRect.set(mMargin, mMargin, bounds.width() - mMargin, bounds.height() - mMargin);
        //mRectBottomR.set( (bounds.width() -mMargin) / 2, (bounds.height() -mMargin)/ 2,bounds.width() - mMargin, bounds.height() - mMargin);
        // mRectBottomL.set( 0,  (bounds.height() -mMargin) / 2, (bounds.width() -mMargin)/ 2, bounds.height() - mMargin);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mPaint);
        //canvas.drawRect(mRectBottomR, mPaint); //only bottom-right corner not rounded
        //canvas.drawRect(mRectBottomL, mPaint); //only bottom-left corner not rounded

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

}
```

Finally, here's my activity code :

```
    RoundCornerDrawable round = new RoundCornerDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.quizcardback),
            getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cardview_radius), 0);
    ImageView imageView=root.findViewById(R.id.quizimage);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        imageView.setBackground(round);
    else
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(round);
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using the card background drawable as following.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/event"></LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. In order to set background image of card, we have to add relative or `LinearLayout`.
2. Add `RelativeLayout` after Cardview declarations such that you can able to move elements within the cards.
   3.Add the following code/Sample is as Follows

   ```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="489dp"
   android:layout_margin="10dp"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview"
   app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
   app:cardElevation="4dp"
   app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/background">
   ```

4.Where `android:background="@drawable/background">` is my image name.

Answer (score 1):

I know its to late for answer but i have easy and smart way for you
make a card view and then make another viewgroup in it
then add backgroundTint for your card view and put the opacity to 0
and then set background image for your other layout you just define in your card view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set background in your linear layout
Like this :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/googleshape1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```